# How do I solve this arithmetic sequences problem?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

Let ${a_n}$ and ${b_n}$ be two different arithmetic series such that $(3n+1)a_n=(2n-1)b_n$ for all positive integers $n$. Let $A_n=a_1+a_2+...+a_n$ and $B_n=b_1+b_2+...+b_n$. what is the value of $\frac{A_9}{B_6}$?

How do I do this? There isn't any info about the separate sequences, but how they are related. Do I need to know anything about the sequences themselves?

Comment: Well, $a_n = b_n\frac {2n _ 1}{3n+1} $ and $b_n = a_n \frac{3n+1}{2n-1}$.  Can you use those?

Comment: Should I plug in $n=1, 2, ...$ into those? Would that work?

Comment: I was just brain storming.  I'd try it with n= 1, 2, or 3.  See if a I see a pattern and try induction.  That's what I'd do.  It may or may not work.

Comment: Or we could do what WW1 suggested which is ... better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n$ and $b_n$ are both arithmetic so can be wrtten in the form ...
$$ 
a_n=k_a+d_an
\\b_n=k_b+d_bn
$$

$$ (3n+1)a_n = (2n-1)b_n 
\\ \implies 3d_a n^2 + (3K-a + d_a)n +k_a = 2 d_b n^2+(2k_b-d_b)n -k_b  $$

This is an identity in $n$ , so we can equate coefficients of powers of $n$ to get a system of 3 equations and 4 unknowns ...

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
k_a &=& -k_b
\\3k_a+d_a &=& 2 k_b-d_b
\\3d_a &=& 2 d_b
\end{eqnarray*}$$

which simplifies to ...
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
k_a &=& -k_b
\\d_b &=& 3 k_b
\\d_a &=& 2 k_b
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Now let $x \equiv k_b$ so that the sequences can be expressed as ...
$$a_n=x(-1+2n)
\\ b_n = x(1+3n)$$

Hopefully you can take it from here, $x$ will cancel when you take the ratio of the sums.

Comment: I see how you got there now :) You had to assume a variable x since there was no way to actually determine the sequences. Is it $\frac{27}{23}$?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to notice that all the elements of both series scale with $a_1$, so we can just set $a_1=1$.  Let the difference of the $a$ series be $k_a$ and the difference of the $b$ series be $k_b$.  Then we can just write the equations for $n=1,2,3$ and get $$4=b_1\\7a_2=3b_2\\10a_3=5b_3
\\7(1+k_a)=3(b_1+k_b)\\10(1+2k_a)=5(b_1+2k_b)\\k_a=2\\k_b=3\\a_n=1+2(n-1)\\b_n=4+3(n-1)$$ and sum the series to get $$A_9=81,B_6=69$$

Answer (score 0):

Note for *any* two arithmetic sequences $a_i = a + i*d$ and $b_i = b + ie$ you have $\frac {a_n}{b_n} = \frac{a+ nd}{b+ ne}= \frac{r(a+ nd)}{r(b+ne)}$

So we have $\frac {a_n}{b_n} = \frac {2n-1}{3n+1}=\frac {r(a + nd)}{r(b+ne)}$

So $a_i = -k +i*(2k)$ and $b_i = k + i*(3k)$ for some real value $k=1/r$.

So $A_n = \sum a_i = -nk + 2k\frac{n(n+1)}2$ and $B_n = \sum b_i = nk + 3k\frac{n(n+1)}2$

and $\frac {A_n}{B_n} = \frac {-nk + kn(n+1)}{nk + 3kn\frac {n+1}2}=\frac{n}{3n + 2.5}$